# Uniform Convergence... What did I wrong for this function?

Tags: analysis, uniform-convergence

[image]

I want to know if this function is unif.conv. or not...

Actually it is one of the my mid-exem problems.

I got zero score for it....

What did I wrong in this problem?

and What is the easiest way to see whether it is unif.conv. or not?

Comment: For  uniform convergence you want $f_n$ to be close to $f$, regardless of $x$. Here you need to pay attention to behavior of $x^n$. IS it true that regardless of $x$ the value of $x^n$ will be close to $0$ (that is when $n$ is beyond some large number?).

Comment: Yes, I think so.. since x in [0,1). x^n goes to zero, when n goes to infinity for any x... (Is it wrong?!!)

Comment: Perhaps if you draw $y=x^n$ for several values of $n$ on $[0,1)$ you will see the snag.

Comment: I can't catch the point...
When x is in [0,1], x^n does not uniformly converges to 0, since x^n is 1 at x=1 for all n.
But in this problem.. x is in [0,1[.
Does this also cause a problem?

Comment: Yes it does. Even though $x=1$ is not in the domain, the points close to it hang high and no matter how large $n$ is there is some $x$ for which $x^n$ is too far away away from $y=0$. As a result it does not converge uniformly. However it does converge pointwise.

Comment: Wow! Now I got it!! How kind of you! thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by $\|\|$? Absolute value or supremum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluate $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ at $x_n:=1-1/n$. You should get $|1+(1-1/n)^n-(1-1/n)^2|$. This has limit $e^{-1}\neq0$.